# Play Framework await() causes UnexpectedException

Tags: java, playframework

I upgraded to Play 1.2.1 this morning so I could make use of their new asynchronous programming with HTTP features.

When I use the example below, from the Play documentation ( * I am
using a different method name * ), I receive an UnexpectedException
error.

```
public static void loopWithoutBlocking() {
    for(int i=0; i<=10; i++) {
        Logger.info(i);
        await("1s");
    }
    renderText("Loop finished");
}
```

The error is as follows:

```
Oops: UnexpectedException

An unexpected error occured caused by exception UnexpectedException:
While applying class play.classloading.enhancers.ContinuationEnhancer
on controllers.Application
```

The example method above is placed within the Application controller and I have included the play.libs.F library.

Does the method using the await() call need to be nested within something deeper?

Comment: I don't get the error? I created a new App (using Play 1.2) and replaced the index method with the code you have above, and it worked fine. I didn't have to import that play.libs.F either (as await is part of Controller). I did have to change Logger, because the compiler complained, but that was all. What version of Java are you using?

Comment: @Codemwnci - Thanks for the reply. I found that when I stripped all code from the Application class and used just the code above then I did not have a problem. For some reason the await() call seemed to clash with an unrelated method. After tidying the code in the other method, the issue resolved itself. I don't think I will ever find out the actual cause of it though.

Comment: It is possible that one of your other methods or attributes accidentally overrode a method in the Controller that await relies on? Glad it has sorted itself anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just in case anybody encounters this same issue (it seems to have been reported by others as well) I thought I had best summarise how I resolved this issue (although it might not be viewed as an 'answer'):

As pointed out by @Codemwnci and [Julien Tournay @ Play-framework google group](http://groups.google.com/group/play-framework/browse_thread/thread/d9846c8dae908ae7#). The code included within the question does actually run.

The actual cause of the error was some 'unrelated' code in the Application class that seemed to conflict with the await() call. After locating the offending method, I tidied up the code, which resulted in the error resolving itself - but I was not able to identify the actual cause of the issue (and trust me, I did look).

So, the answer you ask?

It is not the await() method, it is something else in your code...so comment out everything except the method containing the await() call and locate the code that breaks it.

Have fun finding that!

Comment: I just worked my way through an issue like this today. I ended up doing a bit of house-keeping/refactoring to clean up the impacted controller class. At the end of the day, I only moved methods to other classes that made more sense.

It's worth noting that my failures were occurring only when I had the Play 1.x Cobertura plugin enabled. Prior to refactoring, if I disabled it, the errors went away.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that many bugs regarding await has been fixed after the 1.2.4 release (current one when I'm writting this answer).

So many problems aren't still fixed and I faced the same kind of issues.

But there is an alternate repos, located at : https://github.com/mbknor/play/tree/1.2.4-mbknor-custom-release

that contains the 1.2.4 version of Play with some critical updates/fixes, including those with await.

I tried it and for my problem, it now fixed.

Maybe it will for you.

Now, if Play 1.2.5 is released when you'll read those line, it shouldn't be a problem for you.

Comment: +1 thanks. This was actually an issue with `1.2.2` at the time. I re-wrote the code that was causing me the problem so I cannot check whether any releases actually fixed it - but this information is useful for anyone else who finds they have issues with `await()`.

Answer (score 1):

I've stumbled upon this problem today and I noticed that it was actually caused by **length** of a method. Yes, that is correct, there was one **too long** method in the same class that was causing the problem, after extracting part of it as another method, the problem is gone! So be sure to check your code for that.

Comment: When I had this problem, there was one very oversized method. This method was refactored as part of my debugging of the issue - so I think that you could be on to something here. I don't suppose you have anything that supports it was the long method?

Comment: Not really anything solid, but consistent behavior where when I extracted few lines of the original method into a new method, it started working and I could go back and forth between the two states and it would be perfectly consistent. Also, on a unrelated note, sometimes we had a problem that class wouldn't be enhanced by play so we had to add public static void dummy(){ await("1s");} which would solve this issue. How do I put this? I dislike the framework.